# How to scrape text from a specific table in an html document using Powershell

Tags: powershell, html-parsing

I'm writing a script to pull table data from a website. I'm using

```
New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
```

The first page has a button that is clicked which then pulls up the second page. I create an HTML document and am able to get to the source of the page that contains the table using:

```
$doc2 |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty IHTMLDocument3_documentElement
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty outerhtml
```

But I'm having trouble getting further on,  to the specific table with a `classname` of 'dense'. Once there I will need to extract the 3 TD `innerhtml` values (I think) which is `address`, `owner` and `pin`.

I've seen scripts that use `getElementsByTagName('table')` but that is not recognized and neither is `Where-Object {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'dense'}` for that matter so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Many attempts to get at this section of the document fragement:

```
$doc2 = $ie.Document
$doc2 |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty IHTMLDocument3_documentElement 
| Select-Object -expandproperty outerhtml 
| Where-Object {$_.getElementsByTagName('table')}
| where-object { $_.Class -eq 'dense' } 
| select-object Innertext
```

The expected output is a CSV with `address,ownername,pin` which I will append to a file.

The error I get is:

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'getElementsByTagName'.
>   At C:\scripts\PropertyScrape\PropertyOwnerLookup.ps1:39 char:130
>   + ... ty outerhtml | Where-Object {$_.getElementsByTagName('table')}| where ...
>   +                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

which is similar to the error when trying to get at the classname

The table I need to parse and pull owner name, pin and address from

```
<table class="dense">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Address</th>
   <th>Owner</th>
   <th>PIN</th>
   <th></th>
   <th class="number">Appraisal</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><a id="situsAddressHyperLink" href="realproperty.aspx?pin=99999" Street Address</a></td>    <td>Owner Name</td>
            <td><a id="pinHyperLink" href="realproperty.aspx?pin=99999">99999</a></td>
  </tr>       
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`outerHtml` is of type `string`:

```
$response =Invoke-WebRequest "www.google.com"
$response.ParsedHtml.IHTMLDocument3_documentElement.outerHTML | Get-Member

 TypeName: System.String
 ...
```

You've to call `getElementsByTagName` on `IHTMLDocument3_documentElement`:

```
$response.ParsedHtml.IHTMLDocument3_documentElement.getElementsByTagName("table")
```

Anyhow, though I love PowerShell I would use Python's [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for web scraping issues, since it has good documentation and iterating over different HTML elements is much easier.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this but still comes up blank : $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_documentElement.getElementsByTagName("table") | where-object { $_.Class -eq $tableClassName }  | Select-Object InnerText

Comment: I'm not using invoke-webrequest. The page I am after is on page 2 that comes up following an acceptance page. I'm using an IE object instead, finding the accept button and clicking it then going to the next page.